# What does .class-name mean as a CSS selector?

Tags: css, css-selectors

So if I have a CSS class named "class-name", what does the following mean?

```
.class-name {
  margin: 0;
}
```

And why, if I had the following HTML

```
<div id="some-id">
    <ul>
        <li class="class-name">
    ...
```

would the selector

```
#some-id .class-name ul li
```

not exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first one means what you probably think it means:  Any HTML element with the class `class-name` will have a margin of 0 width (for each side, ie. top, bottom, left and right).

The second question is a bit more subtle.  This selector

```
#some-id .class-name ul li
```

Applies only to an `li` that is found under a `ul`, found under an element with a class of `class-name`, found under an element with id `some-id`.

You would have to use a selector like this to apply to the HTML you have above:

```
#some-id ul li.class-name
```

Note that there is no space between `li` and `.class-name` in that selector.  Specifying `li.class-name` means "an `li` **with** the class name `class-name`", whereas `li .class-name` (with a space) would mean "element with class `class-name` found *below* an `li`".

Comment: So, not even adding the class to the UL would help. I would need to add another level with the class. Is that right?

Comment: That's correct, although there are dozens of ways you could do it.  A more concise way would be to add `class-name` to the `<ul>` element (and remove it from the `<li>`s), and use `#some-id ul.class-name li`.  That way your HTML output would be smaller, as you'd only have `class-name` appear once on the `<ul>` instead of possibly dozens of times on the list elements.

Comment: That's a good suggestion. Makes for some cleaner HTML, it is actually the UL that should control the layout. (As my problem was with a Joomla template, I'll have to pass that on to the Joomla folks ;-)

Answer (score 7):

`.class_name` means select elements with that class.

`#some-id .class-name ul li` means "select the li elements that are within ul elements that are within elements with the class 'class_name' that are within in the inner html of the element named 'some-id'"

Answer (score 3):

```
#some-id ul li.class-name
```

is prob what u need..

```
#some-id .class-name ul li
```

targets li descendants of ul descendants of the class name under #some-id

Answer (score 2):

Because the `class-name` is on the `li` not as an element wrapping the `li`.

To clarify:

```
<div id="some-id">
   <div class="class-name">
     <ul>
       <li>
```

Would match the selector string you mention.

Answer (score 2):

`.class-name` specifies an element that has the class `class-name`. The selector `#some-id .class-name ul li` specifies a `li` that's a descendent of `ul` that's a descendent of some element with the class `class-name` that's a descendent of `#some-id`. To specify a particular kind of element that has the class `class-name`, you would do `tag.class-name` — for example, `div.author-credit`.

Answer (score 1):

That selector expects a `ul` and `li` under an element with `.class-name`. Your HTML structure matches the following selector

```
#some-id ul li.class-name
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got the selector out of order, to select the li's that are "class-name" classes would be:

```
#some-id ul li.class-name
```

Answer (score 0):

Just skip using selectors in most cases.  It makes the css easier to write read and use.  also your programmer.  Yes you can use them to apply CSS  but that what classes are for the ID is for scripts to find elements and replace them or other programs to retrive info from them etc.

You can really screw things up, now or in the future  by using the id's for CSS.